# What is the difference between using Promise.catch() and wrapping a Promise in try...catch?

Tags: javascript, try-catch, es6-promise

I was sitting in listening to a Javascript class today and they were covering something I hadn't seen before and which I don't fully understand.  I will try to reproduce as best I can from memory

Instead of using the `catch` of a Promise to handle errors, which I'm used to, the teacher used `try...catch` wrapped around the Promise and its `then`s.  When I asked him why he did this, he said it was to catch the error 'synchronously'.  That is, instead of the following format (I'm using pseudocode), which I'm used to

```
someLibrary.someFunctionThatReturnsAPromise
.then(() => something)
.then(() => somethingElse)
.catch(err => reportError)
```

he did it thus

```
try {
 someLibrary.someFunctionThatReturnsAPromise
    .then(() => something)
    .then(() => somethingElse)
} 
catch(err) {
  reportError
}
```

What would be the difference between these two ways of catching the error? 
How would wrapping a Promise, which is asynchronous, report errors in a synchronous fashion?

Thanks for any insights!

Comment: The second example block will only catch synchronous errors not async ones. So theoretically if you don't care about whether your async succeeds and only about execution errors it would be effective. `try {} catch () {} ` can be used to catch if you are using async/await, is it possible the teacher was demonstrating that ?

Answer (score 3):

The `try-catch` won't catch asynchronous errors around a `<somePromise>.then` since as you've noticed, the block will exit before the promise has finished/potentially thrown.

However, if you are using `async`/`await` then the `try-catch` will catch since the block will wait for the `await`:

```
async function foobar() {
  try {
    await doSomePromise();
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `try/catch` version will only catch the error if the error is thrown when the *initial* (synchronous) code is running - it will not catch errors that are thrown inside any of the `.then`s:

```js
try {
  Promise.resolve()
    .then(() => {
      throw new Error()
    });
} catch(e) {
  console.log('caught');
}
```

So, the only way an error will be caught with `try/catch` in your code is if `someLibrary.someFunctionThatReturnsAPromise` throws synchronously. On the other hand, the `.then`/`.catch` version will catch *any* error (and is almost certainly preferable).

Answer (score 1):

1. catch after then (first example)
   it is a short way to to handle only error from your promise. It is the same as
   .then(null, (err) => reportError)
   as then takes two parameters: for fulfilled and rejected state of the promise.
2. try catch block (second example)
   in short - is is a common way to handle your code block. if you what from your code not only failed but do something after it. Try/catch is working only in sync mode, that is why if you work with async code, you should wrap it, for example in async/await way.

Actually you can also you use 3 statement after catch - finally, but it depends )